# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined in django and react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm following the react and django tutorial, and I keep running into an issue when i add some code for concern with.

The error `'Cannot read property 'map' of undefined'`

is thrown.

Error place is shown as in `layout.js`

```py
> 53 |   <Dropdown.Menu>
  54 |  ^    {cart &&
```

Error place is shown as in `cart.js`

```py
> 33 |     dispatch(cartSuccess(res.data));
  34 | ^   })
```

In **Layout.js**

```py
<Dropdown.Menu>
    {cart &&
    cart.order_items.map(order_item => {
        return (
        <Dropdown.Item key={order_item.id}>
            {order_item.quantity} *{order_item.item}
        </Dropdown.Item>
            );
        })}
        {cart && cart.order_items.length < 1 ? (
            <Dropdown.Item>No items in your cart</Dropdown.Item>
        ) : null}
```

In **Cart.js**

```js
export const fetchCart = () => {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(cartStart());
    authAxios
      .get(orderSummaryURL)
      .then(res => {
        dispatch(cartSuccess(res.data));
      })
      .catch(err => {
        dispatch(cartFail(err));
      });
  };
};
```

Comment: Try `cart &&
    cart.order_items && cart.order_items.map...` because order_items in cart might be undedined

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is telling you that `cart.order_items` is `undefined`.

To avoid this error, change

```
<Dropdown.Menu>
  {cart &&
  cart.order_items.map(order_item => {
    return ( ...
```

to

```
<Dropdown.Menu>
  {cart && cart.order_items &&
  cart.order_items.map(order_item => {
    return ( ...
```

That will make the error go away, because you're now explicitly checking the existence of `order_items`. But, I can't tell you why `cart.order_items` is undefined without knowing more about the app (more code).